# Custom jndi object factory in wildfly 8 for CDI

Tags: mongodb, jndi, cdi, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

I am trying to achieve injecting a jndi resource using CDI for wildfly 8.
For this purpose i want to use a custom jnidfactory as developed in https://github.com/juanlmelo/mongo-jndi-plugin/

The problem is due to my limited knowledge in wildfly, I don't know the following.

1) how to activate/attach this jndifactory in wildfly, ofcourse I can create an object while startup and assign a jndi name to it programmatically , but want to explore custom factory feature of wildfly

2) the best practice to set the uri property needed by the object factory, i assume using System.getProperty inside the factory should suffice , as the DB uri will be different for each installation

once this is achieved I am confident I can get it injected into my classes using cdi.

I have tried my best to look for similar post, but couldn't find any, if you think this is duplicate please point me to the correct one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you want add custom JNDI factory to wildfly using `https://github.com/juanlmelo/mongo-jndi-plugin/` you need to do few things:

1) You need to change a little bit implementation of `https://github.com/juanlmelo/mongo-jndi-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mongodb/jndi/MongoClientJNDIFactory.java`

- line 38 change to: 

`String mongoURI = (String) environment.get(MONGO_CLIENT_URI);`

and comment out or delete lines 39-49

2) then run command `mvn clean package` and create directory eg.: 

`wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/com/mongodb/jndi/main/`

copy there `mongo-jndi-plugin-1.0.jar` and create there `module.xml` file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mongodb.jndi">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mongo-jndi-plugin-1.0.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
         <module name="com.mongodb.driver"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

3) add mongo driver

-create directory: `wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/com/mongodb/driver/main`

-create there file: `module.xml` and place there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mongodb.driver">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mongo-java-driver-2.11.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
</dependencies> 
</module>
```

-add to this directory `mongo-java-driver-2.11.0.jar` library

4) add something like this
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
    <bindings>
      <object-factory name="java:global/MongoClient" module="com.mongodb.jndi" class="com.mongodb.jndi.MongoClientJNDIFactory">
          <environment>
            <property name="mongoClientURI" value="mongodb://username:password@yourdomain.com:27017,username:password@yourdomain.com:27017"/>
          </environment>
      </object-factory>
    </bindings>
    <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>`

to your `domain.xml` or `standalone.xml`

**voilà**
After this steps you can inject MongoClient into your classes using @Resource annotation (eg. `@Resource(lookup = "java:global/MongoClient"`

Comment: thanks for this response, currently I made a simple Producer for this to continue working , but I will move it to JNDI driver soon and If I understand it right, this is actually an example of defining modules and exposing them as JNDI resource in WildFly server